# why blocked by CORS policy even after 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'

Tags: angularjs, flask

I have flask api(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/out/`) which return the json. Angular js is `http://localhost:4300` also running

I have added the extension `Moesif Orign & CORS Changer` and switched on also `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'`

Error is below

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/out/' from origin 'http://localhost:4300' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Already gone the link [Why does my JavaScript code get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-pr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix with below code

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@cross_origin(origin='*')
```